# Multiple if statement returning css value depending on URL

Tags: javascript, css, url, if-statement

The script works but their seems to be a bug causing the first and last if statement to implement the style no matter what page it is on. The middle if statement does not display.

I have also tried a break and return after each if statement but that completely brakes the script and does not display anything on the page.

```
window.onload = function()
{ 
var ThisStyle = "background-color: #4C4C4C; color: #fff; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px; border-top-right-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;"

if (document.URL.indexOf("index.php"))
{
    document.getElementById("home-nav").style.cssText = ThisStyle;
}

else if (document.URL.indexOf("about.php"))
{
    document.getElementById("about-nav").style.cssText = ThisStyle;
}

else (document.URL.indexOf("products.php"))
{
    document.getElementById("products-nav").style.cssText = ThisStyle;
}
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you have a `if ` missing in `else (document.URL.indexOf("products.php"))`

Comment: Even with that change the issue still persists

Comment: need to use class instead http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h8z4h9qn/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h8z4h9qn/6/

Comment: tried all of your help thus far but nothing seems to be working. I dont exactly want to upload the whole site but would a fiddle version help?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/markvbaustin/59z6saes/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems here, as I mentioned earlier `if` was missing in the last statement, also indexOf() will return -1 if the item is not found which is a truthy value so always your first condition will be true

A more appropriate solution will be to use a class

```
.active {
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

then

```
window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.URL,
        id;
    if (url.indexOf("index.php") > -1) {
        id = 'home-nav';
    } else if (url.indexOf("about.php") > -1) {
        id = 'about-nav';
    } else if (url.indexOf("products.php") > -1) {
        id = 'products-nav';
    }
    if (id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (el.classList) {
            el.classList.add('active')
        }else{
            el.className+= ' active'
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h8z4h9qn/)

Comment: I felt this was getting close but I am still having the same issue it seems

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/markvbaustin/59z6saes/1/ and here is a copy of the site on google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8rJaCz44Qq0NW5TVnZXTnhNcEU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the comparison of the indexOf, if you get -1 or 0 i think it will be entering the conditions even if you dont want to, try this:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var ThisStyle = "background-color: #4C4C4C; color: #fff; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px; border-top-right-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;"

    if (document.URL.indexOf("index.php") > -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("home-nav").style.cssText = ThisStyle;
    }

    else if (document.URL.indexOf("about.php") > -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("about-nav").style.cssText = ThisStyle;
    }

    else
        (document.URL.indexOf("products.php") > -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("products-nav").style.cssText = ThisStyle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this before but to be sure I tried it and it still causes me to have the same issue sadly

Answer (score 0):

indexOf returns -1 if not found. That is going to be truthy.

You need to add a check for `!= -1`

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("xxxx") != -1) {
```

Comment: Is this similar to what Arun P Johny mentioned, or a different idea. js is not my strong suit